# Getting a pointer to my XDisplay (Linux) (X)?

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

I need to be able to access the X Event Loop to add clipboard support for a game API.  The problem is the game API does not know which API it will use for display (It could use SDL or other). As a result, I do not have direct access to the X event loop. Is there a function in XLib to get a pointer to my display so that I can process messages and add clipboard support?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it runs on X11, there has to be a Display pointer in the graphics object *somewhere*. You can allocate a new one with `XOpenDisplay(NULL);` but that's not likely to achieve what you want. You'd still have to find the Windows and other info which is tricky enough when a program does it *once.*

You really need to dig through the existing code to find the X11 module. There's likely to be a single function that performs on iteration of the "Event Loop" as a subroutine of the *real* "main Processing Loop". If you can't simply add your new code there, you can at least see how the program already accesses this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenGL for graphics, you can exploit that. At some point in the program where you know, the OpenGL context is made current call [`glXGetCurrentDisplay`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glXGetCurrentDisplay.xml). However you should be carefull not to interfere with the programs main event loop.